# Image plotted by plt.imshow() is inverted while same image by cv2_imshow() is fine, how do I know what my neural net gets?

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, mediapipe

Here is my snippet for both of them

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow 
import cv2 
pt = '/content/content/DATA/testing_data/1/126056495_AO_BIZ-0000320943-Process_IP_Cheque_page-0001.jpg' #@param
img = cv2.imread(pt) 
cv2_imshow(img)
```

and here is the other one

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

pt = '/content/content/DATA/testing_data/1/126056495_AO_BIZ-0000320943-Process_IP_Cheque_page-0001.jpg'
image = mpimg.imread(pt)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Now, the image in second case is inverted
and image on my system is upright

What I am mostly afraid of is, if my ML model is consuming inverted image, that is probably messing with my accuracy. What could possibly be the reason to It and how do I fix it

(ps: I cannot share the pictures unfortunately, as they are confidential )
(Run on google colab)
All the help is appreciated

Comment: @M.Spiller no it does not
As they propose a solution of inverting it back, and if I do that, it will mess with other images in my dataset which are plotten nicely

Comment: [mre] please...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz edited it, but cannot give away an image, as they are real cheques of a bank and cannot generate a sample which would act weirdly, because idk why its acting weirdly :(

Comment: Is the image greyscale or RGB[A].  If it's greyscale, Matplotlib is probably color mapping it.

Comment: @JodyKlymak it is RGB actually

Comment: you could have scanned _anything else_ and that would have demonstrated the issue. we need to _see_ what you see. show us the problem, don't just tell us. words are often misunderstood. at least I misunderstood, initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picture is **upside-down** when you use one method for reading, and upright when you use the other method?

You use two different methods to read the image file:

- OpenCV `cv.imread()`
- Mediapipe `mpimg.imread()`

They behave differently. OpenCV's `imread()` respects file metadata and rotates the image as instructed. Mediapipe's function does not.

**Solution:** Stick to OpenCV's `imread()`. Don't use Mediapipe's function.

---

The issue *is **not** with matplotlib*. When `plt.imshow()` is called, it presents the image with an origin in the top left corner, i.e. the Y-axis grows downward. That corresponds to how `cv.imshow()` behaves.

If your plot *does* have an Y-axis growing upwards, causing the image to stand upside-down, then you must have set this plot up in specific ways that aren't presented in your question.